# Scales of Measurement in a university grading table

Tags: statistics

[Grading Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzeK1.jpg)

In the table above, I am trying to differentiate the different scales of measurement. After thinking and doing some research, I concluded that the first two columns belong to the ordinal scale. As for the last column, I saw different opinions and papers that states that it is interval, but others stated its a ratio scale.

I concluded that it belongs to the interval scale because 5.0 does not necessarily mean 2.5 times 2.0.

Apart from that I need an answer for the 3rd column... I believe it is a ratio scale, but because the differences in the ranges are not equal I am having doubts. Can someone enlighten me?